# How would the standard allow indirection through a null pointer?

Tags: c++, reference, standards

EDIT: This is related to active issue 232 on the [C++ Standard Core Language Active Issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232)

So the real question is how would the standard allow indirection through a null pointer?

Consider the following code:

```
struct a { int x; };
struct b { int y; };

struct c: a, b { };

b *f(c *pointer_to_c) { return pointer_to_c; }
```

`f(...)` has to test if `pointer_to_c` is `NULL` and return `NULL` if it is. (A `NULL` pointer is always a `NULL` pointer, no matter how you cast it.)

Now, consider the following:

```
b *f_ref(c &reference_to_c) { return &reference_to_c; }
```

First question: does `f_ref` need to check if `&reference_to_c` is `NULL`?
Second question: if C++ eventually defines the behavior of indirection through a null pointer, does this mean `f_ref` has to check for `NULL`? (I suppose the answer depends on what the standard allows, i.e., if it says "casting a NULL reference to a base class is undefined for multiple inheritance", then the answer is clearly no.)

For one last puzzle, now consider this:

```
const b *f_const_ref(const c &reference_to_c) { return &reference_to_c; }
```

Does `f_const_ref` have to check `&reference_to_c` to `NULL`? Incidentally, with VC++ 2010, all three functions got optimized to `f`, that is, all three functions test the input against `NULL`.

So given that you cannot pass a null reference in a well-defined program, does that mean that if the C++ standard eventually allows indirection through a null pointer it cannot result in an expression or subexpression that would otherwise bind to a null pointer and create a null reference? In other words, if the standard allows indirection through a null pointer, what are the various ways they could allow it?

Comment: You can't really have a null reference in C++, can you?

Comment: I thought you couldn't have a null reference? And why does the compiler need to check if the pointer is `NULL` and return `NULL` if it is when it could just return the value either way? I guess I don't understand a lot of things.

Comment: It doesn't really say that dereferencing a null pointer is ok, it just proposes that expressions like `&*p` should be valid even in some cases where `*p` might not be. Still just a proposal though!

Answer (score 6):

De-referencing a NULL pointer is invalid (i.e. Undefined behavior).

Thus it is never possible to get a reference from a NULL (in valid code).

Thus any reference you get will never be NULL and thus you do not need to check for it.

> First question: does f_ref need to check if &reference_to_c is NULL?

No.

> Second question: if C++ eventually defines the behavior of indirection through a null pointer does this mean f_ref has to check for NULL?

It does. Its undefined behavior. Thus any further speculation is worthless.

> For one last puzzle, Does f_const_ref have to check &reference_to_c to NULL?

No.

Comment: about the sentence _f(...) has to test if pointer_to_c is NULL and return NULL if it is._ Is that true?

Comment: The sentence is meaningless. If C is not derived from B it is a compile time error. If it is casting a NULL pointer to the base class results in NULL.

Comment: So then it's completely wrong? I thought so, it would be stupid to do that. It's like `return ptr == NULL ? NULL : ptr;`

Comment: @Martin, I worded the question poorly. I'm curious as to what the standard could allow if it allowed indirection through a null pointer, i.e., &(*(char *)0).

Comment: OK. I see where you are coming from and I agree that references to one past the end of an array/container should be valid (as long as you don't de-reference it). But I disagree that with the ability to convert a NULL to a reference, that opens up a whole can of worms that makes the language more complex (thus I am glad it was not resolved this way in the current draft standard  (n3242)).

Answer (score 3):

If your reference in `f_ref` or `f_const_ref` is NULL, you are deep in the realm of undefined behavior.

This is undefined because the only way to get a NULL reference is to dereference a NULL pointer.  So the below is undefined, though on g++ 4.5.2 it will output 0.

```
#include <iostream>
struct C {};
C* foo(C& r) {  return &r; }
int main() {
  C* c = NULL;

  std::cout << foo(*c) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does g++ let you dereference a null pointer without crashing?

Comment: @Seth : Because compiling without warnings/errors is one of the myriad manifestations of UB, as is appearing to execute correctly at runtime.

Comment: Mostly because I'm neither reading nor writing to address zero, so it doesn't crash.

Comment: There is no dereferencing of a null pointer in this example. There is nothing in the standard that says that `foo(*c)` will actually dereference that pointer. Just the opposite; how references are implemented is up to the implementation. References are typically implemented as pointers, so that `foo(*c)` is really just pass by value in g++ (and in every other implementation I know of). What this example is doing is creating a null reference, which is a different kind of undefined behavior than dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does *not* allow this. The reference to `NULL`is illegal and standards-wise will result in undefined behaviour.

Having said that, I've never seen a compiler do anything other than your expectation.

Comment: Why *reference to NULL* is illegal and UB? A `&ref` cannot be NULL and what you said, is two different thing.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sure it can. It is (unfortunately) rather easy to create a null reference.

Comment: In fact, I am chasing down a stupid null reference bug at this very moment.

Comment: I got the bug. In a key spot I didn't have a protection against null pointers, and I happened to invoke my code in a way that generated a null pointer. C++ gladly converted that null pointer to a null reference when I passed `*ptr` as a parameter to a function that takes a `Foo & ref` as an argument. The program crashed of course, but the crash didn't occur until later (much later) when it tried to do something with that null reference.

Answer (score 1):

`&reference_to_c` can never be NULL. In a function parameter, a reference has to be initialized with some valid object. So `&reference_to_c` cannot be NULL.

Comment: Re "a reference has to be initialized with some valid object": That is only true in a well-defined program. I don't know about you, but I've written plenty of ill-defined programs in my time. Programs only become fairly well-defined after plowing through all the bugs found by internal testing and bug reports from disgruntled customers. Even then there's no guarantee that the program truly is well-defined. The odds are almost certain that there is a latent bug hiding somewhere if the code is anything more than a toy program.

Comment: There still is not much point in testing for the hypothetical "null reference", as you have already got your UB long before it is created. After that, further tests are not reliable anyway, and subject to removal by the optimizer (which can assume well defined code).